# crontab not running simple job

Tags: cron, reboot

i have a very simple command in cron that should reboot my system everyday. I modified crontab in root with the following:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

I then added one line to the end of the crontab:

```
0 1 * * * reboot
```

And finally added one blank line after the line above. However the system is still not rebooting the box at 1 AM as specified.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Cron usually needs a full file path try using `0 1 * * * /sbin/reboot` instead